# How to reduce Web RTC noise, clicking sound during conversation

Tags: reactjs, webrtc

I have created an app with a live conversation module in javascript. I am using WebRTC to set up the Peer connection. Signaling and candidates all seem to work correctly. The peers are not on the same network.

At some point, the audio starts to add clicks to the stream. The quality starts to fail quite fast.

I have tried to reduce bitrates but to no avail. The code to reduce bitrate looks like this:

```
function setMediaBitrates(sdp, videoRate = 250, audioRate = 50) {
    let f = navigator.userAgent.search("Firefox");
    let modifier = 'AS';
    // if (f > -1) {
    //     videoRate = (videoRate >>> 0) * 1000;
    //     audioRate = (audioRate >>> 0) * 1000;
    //     modifier = 'TIAS';
    // }

    //find the correct m lines (video and audio)
    var lines = sdp.sdp.split("\n");
    let i = 0;
    while (i < lines.length) {
        //if we find an m-line
        if (lines[i].indexOf("m=") === 0) {
            let video = lines[i].indexOf("m=video") === 0;
            let audio = lines[i].indexOf("m=audio") === 0;

            if (video || audio) {
                while(i < lines.length && (lines[i].indexOf("i=") === 0 || lines[i].indexOf("c=") === 0)) {
                    i++;
                }

                // If we're on a b line, replace it
                if (i < lines.length && lines[i].indexOf("b") === 0) {
                    lines[i] = `b=${modifier}:${video ? videoRate : audioRate}`;
                } else if (i == lines.length) {
                    lines.push(`b=${modifier}:${video ? videoRate : audioRate}`);
                    i++;
                } else {
                    i++;
                    lines.splice(i, 0, `b=${modifier}:${video ? videoRate : audioRate}`);
                }
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    
    let s = lines.join("\n");    
    return { type : sdp.type, sdp : s };
}
```

With rate limiting, I have about 15 minutes of good audio, and after that static starts to appear.

I am starting the peer connection using the following ReactJS code:

```
pc
.createOffer({ offerToReceiveVideo : useVideo ? 1 : 0 })
.then(sdp => {
  pc.setLocalDescription(sdp);

  let newSdp = setMediaBitrates(sdp);
  dispatch(sendWebRTCSdp(activeConversationId, newSdp));
})
.catch(e => {});
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use `MediaTrackSettings.noiseSuppression` but it still has compatibility issues with safari. you could also disable `echoCancellation` because sometimes hardware noise suppression can have weird effects on slow internet.
I remember I had a problem with the clicking sound but it was just these parameters that should be given to `getUserMedia()` and I made sure to set `myVideo.muted = true;` in which `myVideo` is the video element on the page it should be muted so that your voice and the other person's voice don't echo repeatedly through both of your audio output devices.

some sources that helped me: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/12/disabling-hardware-noise-suppression

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackSettings/noiseSuppression

Comment: I will try and see if that works. Thanks for the answer.